# How can i add custom.less file for a specific store in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How can we add custom.less file for specific store in magento 2 ?

**Description:**  Assume we have 2 stores,in *store 1* i want to create `custom1.less` and in *store 2* i want to add `custom2.less` file so how it will be possible ?

Comment: Please suggwest me what to do @Teja Bhagavan Kollepara